# MySQL count columns in table by name

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to count the number of columns in a table by their name?

eg

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%name%'
AND table_schema = 'DB_NAME' AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

I have a table that adds columns to a table for custom fields added by the user and I need to it count the added columns to use the result in a while loop

Comment: What is this `%LIKE%` operator of yours?

Comment: sorry, long night and little sleep, didn't think it looked right, editing now

Comment: To be slightly less wilfully-ignorant (;P) - the `%` wildcards are meant to go around the sought string, not the LIKE keyword, i.e. `LIKE '%name%'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. There's a chance that you need to use `COLUMN_NAME` in the `WHERE` in place of `COLUMN` -- at least, that's how it is listed in the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%name%'
   AND table_schema = 'DB_NAME'
   AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query **LIKE**

Place `LIKE %'name'%` as `LIKE '%name%'`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could also work:

```
SELECT T.name, COUNT(C.name) FROM sys.tables T
INNER JOIN sys.columns C ON C.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE T.name = ('TableName') and C.name like '%name%'
GROUP BY T.name
```

This would work within a database.